# Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream')

Tags: javascript, html, css, mime-types

I have an issue with importing css and javascript when using versioning.
It appears that when I use styles.css and script.js, everything is working fine, but when I use **styles.css?v=1.1** or **script.js?v=1.1** - i get the below errors.

```
Refused to apply style from 'url/goes/here/styles.css?v=1.1' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Refused to execute script from 'url/goes/here/script.js?v=2.1' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

What can be the reason of this ?!

They are imported like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url/goes/here/styles.css?v=1.1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="url/goes/here/script.js?v=1.1"></script>
```

Comment: After more digging, it seems that if i visit the url with styles.css - it shows the css file in the browser. If i visit the url with styles.css?v=1.1 it will download the css file. Maybe that is why is changing the mime-type to application/octet-stream instead of text/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on the server, go and change the `"content-type"` of the css file to `"text/css"` and js file to `"text/javascript"`, that should solve the problem